# Is there a way to mark content as random?

Tags: seo, ranking, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to have search engines not index a certain section of a page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/is-there-any-way-to-have-search-engines-not-index-a-certain-section-of-a-page)

**Is there a way to mark a section of a webpage (div) so that it is not considered for ranking?**

What I am seeing is that sometimes a page ranks for a keyword which is not permanently on that page but only there randomly or semi-randomly. For example, a div may show a random image, or the most popular item or article for that day, or simply a random quote. It gives something interesting for recurring visitors but when the enclosing page ranks for keywords which appeared in those sections (and may no longer appear) is feels less than ideal.