# How to prevent a search engines from indexing a section of a page?

Tags: search-engines, search-engine-indexing

I have many pages with lots of text in it. But I will always have two sections of text and I want to prevent one section from appearing in search results, the other section must be indexed.

```
<p class="please-index-me">text</p>

<p class="get-out">never index me please</p>
```

I thought that maybe if I load the "please don't index me text" with JavaScript maybe search engines wouldn't look for it. But I am not sure it would work and this is not really nice.

I was wondering if there is a way to tell search engines "hey, this text you can't grab, move on". So, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yeah. I don't don't of any feature to do that sort of a thing although Google understands all sorts of markers, but I've seen one that says "do not index". The IFRAME solution proposed is pretty the only one I could think of.

Comment: [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/16390/17633)

Comment: [Is there any way to have search engines not index a certain section of a page?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/1355/17633)

Answer (score 5):

[One way I found here](http://moz.com/blog/12-ways-to-keep-your-content-hidden-from-the-search-engines), is using an `<iframe>` and blocking the URL in *robots.txt*.

[image: block text section]

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what type of search results, and I think it also depends on the search engine.

From what I can tell, the [techniques outlined here](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/610/admin_crawl/Preparing) only work for the 'Google Custom Search' tool (results within the site, not results on Google).

Also, I can't recall exactly how but I think Yahoo has a method that let's you apply a class to an element (i.e. something like `<p class="yahoo-no-index">`) to have it excluded from crawling.

I doubt that's exactly what you are looking for but perhaps it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may be possible is to keep the section you do not want indexing in a collapsed `<div>`. You can then use some button to trigger a JavaScript/jQuery event and inject the content into the `<div>`.

```
$(".get-out").html("Enter the content you do not want indexing here.");
```

As long as the visibilty is invoked by a user action (i.e. clicking a button) this will not be considered as [cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking).

You may also be able to use a modal box like [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/). I'm really not sure if this will fit in with your format but it will solve the indexing problem.